# Android Studio onStart not execute

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am facing a problem with the following situation. I have an activity and if I put a break point it stops in the onCreate function, and I can debug every line of code in that function. But another life cycle function, the onStart never got called, the break point putted there never got executed.
I am correct, onStart is the second life cycle function in the lifecycle, and onResume is the third. I tried onResume, and nothing again.
Here is the some part of my activity class where I have this issue:

```
class GameActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{
    private var settings: Settings = Settings(1, 2, 2, 2)
    private var _settingsRepository: SettingsRepository? = null;

    private var _handler: Handler = Handler()
    private var _runnable: Runnable = Runnable {  }

    private var counter: Int = 0

    private var _adapter: GridElementAdapter? = null;
    private var _gridElementList: List<GridElement> = ArrayList<GridElement>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game)

        _settingsRepository = SettingsRepository(this.applicationContext)
        settings = _settingsRepository!!.read()

        gridView.numColumns = settings.column
        gridView.setExpanded(true)

        val windowSize: Size = getGridSize()

        _gridElementList = getData()
        _adapter = GridElementAdapter(this, _gridElementList, settings, windowSize)
        gridView.adapter = _adapter
    }

    override fun onStart()
    {
        super.onStart()

        hideGridViewElements()
        //startCounter()
    }

    private fun hideGridViewElements()
    {
         var indexOrder: ArrayList<Int> = ArrayList<Int>()

        for (i in 0 .. gridView.adapter.count)
        {
            indexOrder.add(i)
        }

        indexOrder.shuffle()

        for (i in indexOrder)
        {
            var gridChild: ImageView = gridView.getChildAt(i) as ImageView;
            gridChild.visibility = View.INVISIBLE;
            Thread.sleep((settings!!.speed * 1000).toLong())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that your Activity is crashing at some point during `onCreate` and never reaches the `onStart` state?

Comment: when I debug onCreate it never throws an exception, and it goes to an end without any problem